# Desativar um submit e Ativar somente quando o mínimo de radio buttons estiver selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tentei fazer uma função mas saiu com alguns bugs estranhos, tem que ser mais ou menos [este](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/BPhZe/76/) script, mas habilitar o botão somente se 5 ou mais radio buttons forem marcados. Lembrando que meu formulário é enorme, é um questionário que tem grupos de radio, por exemplo:

```
<input type="radio" name="group[001]" id="1">apple
<input type="radio" name="group[001]" id="2">pineapple
<input type="radio" name="group[001]" id="3">melon
...
<input type="radio" name="group[002]" id="4">strawberry
<input type="radio" name="group[002]" id="5">orange
<input type="radio" name="group[002]" id="6">kiwi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podes verificar á medida que o utilizador está a escolher as opções se já tem 5 ou mais para ativar o botão:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/93ETf/)

```
// desactiva por defeito
$('form button').html('Tens que escolher mínimo 5').prop('disabled', true);

// controla se tem mínimo 5 escolhidos para activar
$('form').on("click", 'input[type="radio"]', function (e) {
    if ($("form input:radio:checked").length >= 5) {
        $('form button').html('Enviar').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('form button').html('Tens que escolher mínimo 5').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

**Notas:**

Estou a usar o `.html()` meramente para informar o utilizador com uma mensagem adequada, mas não é minimamente necessário para o que pretendes, é só um toque de UI.

---

O código na sua versão que não faz uso da mensagem ao utilizador ficaria ainda mais reduzido:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Lvj3k/)

```
// desactiva por defeito
$('form button').prop('disabled', true);

// controla se tem mínimo 5 escolhidos para activar
$('form').on("click", 'input[type="radio"]', function (e) {
    $('form button').prop('disabled', ($("form input:radio:checked").length < 5));
});
```

<sup>**Nota:** A verificação aqui é invertida, porque a `.prop("disable")` espera `true` para desativar.</sup>

Comment: é bem isso ai mesmo @Zuul +1 para sua resposta!

Comment: +1 Resposta bem completa!

Answer (score 3):

É possível percorrer os `radios` marcados e contar a quantos tem.

Veja o exemplo:

```js
$('input').change(function() {

    //habilita/desabilita botão
    $('button').prop('disabled', 
           $('input[type="radio"]:checked').length < 5);

});
```

#### [Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/aEEEu/)

Comment: Tinha esquecido que não precisa verificar se mais de um radio está marcado. Que burro, dá zero pra ele!

Comment: Pois, eu estava a olhar para o teu código a ver se entendia o porque! :) +1 Agora

Answer (score 2):

Adicione no evento "change" de cada input uma função que verifique a quantidade de de input que estão marcados, caso seja o número que você deseja, você pode setar a propriedade disabled do "submit" como "false", caso contrario, como "true".

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo desse tipo:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(
    function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').prop("disabled",    ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').toArray().length>=5));

   }});
```

Comment: o problema nesse caso é que cada vez que um checkbox for alterado o jQuery vai varrer o Dom em busca dos checkboxes alterados. Se todos os itens que você precisa já estão carregados no DOM o melhor a fazer é guardar a referência à eles em algum lugar(var).

Comment: Depende muito do quanto o desempenho é relevante. Se está sendo usado jQuery em vez de js puro, imagino que isso não seja a prioridade.

Comment: Mesmo que performance não seja um requisito crítico para o caso dele, acho que ficar varrendo o DOM continuamente é desnecessário. E usar jQuery não deve ser uma desculpa para relaxarmos com o código.

Comment: Na minha humilde opinião, relaxar nó código e fazer uso de variáveis globais quando não há necessidade.

Comment: Não serão variáveis globais se estiverem dentro de uma (function(){}()) ou $(document).ready(function(){}) por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Dá pra simplificar bastante a lógica de enable/disable.

Adicionando um handler ao click ou change dos radio buttons.

http://jsfiddle.net/moykn/nY4g5/

Lembrando que em caso de radio button apenas um de cada grupo pode ser selecionado.